# Quantum Neural Network (statevector generation) with qiskit and pytorch

Tags: pytorch, quantum-computing, qiskit

I am implementing variational quantum circuit that takes inputs of Statevectors(similar to [RawFeatureVector](https://qiskit-community.github.io/qiskit-machine-learning/stubs/qiskit_machine_learning.circuit.library.RawFeatureVector.html)) and produce some Statevector-like-results (qiskit [Statevector](https://docs.quantum.ibm.com/api/qiskit/0.45/qiskit.quantum_info.Statevector) or (n(=number of qubits) X 2) matrix, arrays, or else) with parameterized rotation gates(rx, ry, or rz gates) using Qiskit.

I tried to build the circuit by myself and connect it to Pytorch with [TorchConnector](https://qiskit-community.github.io/qiskit-machine-learning/stubs/qiskit_machine_learning.connectors.TorchConnector.html), the backward process goes wrong (the gradients did not spread out to update the weight parameters) because I could not provide appropriate backward function.
I also read the documents and examples using [SamplerQNN](https://qiskit-community.github.io/qiskit-machine-learning/stubs/qiskit_machine_learning.neural_networks.SamplerQNN.html) or [EstimatorQNN](https://qiskit-community.github.io/qiskit-machine-learning/stubs/qiskit_machine_learning.neural_networks.EstimatorQNN.html), but all of their examples that I explored were based on the many-shots based simulation, so I thought it was slightly different from what I expected (I want to get the Statevector representation of the circuit instead of the measurement outcome).

Question: is there any way to build a quantum neural network (SamplerQNN or EstimatorQNN) that does the above behavior using Qiskit?
Or, are there any other ways I can try to build such QNN?

Here is some simplified snippet of what I want to do.

```py
# Might be wrong in syntax 
# but kindly ask you to take this as the pseudocode that I want to do..
class Model(nn.module):
    def __init__(self):
        # do some initialization if needed

    def quantum_circuit(self, weights, n_qubit):
        # weights: torch.tensor that needs autograd

        fm = RawFeatureVector(n_qubit) # circuit for feature map
        rc = QuantumCircuit(n_qubit) # circuit with rotation gates
        for i in range(n_qubit):
            rc.rx(weights[3*i], i)
            rc.ry(weights[3*i+1], i)
            rc.rz(weights[3*i+2], i)
        for i in range((n_qubit//2)):
            rc.cx(2*i, 2*i+1)

        qc = QuantumCircuit(n_qubit)
        qc.compose(fm)
        qc.compose(rc)

        return qc

def train(inputs, initial_weights, n_qubit, target_statevector):
    # input: torch.tensor with/without autograd
    max_iter = 100
    weights = ParameterVector('a', 3*n_qubit)
    weight_params = torch.from_numpy(initial_weights)
    weight_params.requires_grad = True

    model = Model()
    qc, fm, rc = model.quantum_circuit(weights, n_qubit)
    simulator = Aer.get_backend('statevector_simulator')

    # QNN that returns the Statevector(qc) as an output of 'forward' method
    # Use statevector_simulator to get the statevector of the result..?
    qnn = QNN(qc, fm.parameters, rc.parameters, simulator)

    torch_connector = TorchConnector(qnn, initial_weights)

    optimizer = torch.optim.Adam([weight_params], lr = 0.01)

    torch_connector.train()
    for iter in range(max_iter):
        # outputs the statevector of the qnn with the inputs and weight_params
        statevector = qnn.forward(inputs, weight_params) 
        # loss function using statevector and target_statevector as tensors
        loss = loss_function(statevector, target_statevector) 
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        # autograd, update weight_params with regard to the circuit in qnn
        loss.backward() 
        optimizer.step()

    return weight_params # return optimal parameter of the model
```

I am using qiskit 0.45.3 (maybe I can update this to 1.0.0) and qiskit_machine_learning 0.7.1, qiskit_aer 0.13.3, qiskit_algorithms 0.2.2, Python 3.11.5.